# How to remove the last comma when using for loop?

Tags: .net, angularjs, angular, for-loop

> I have to display a message after performing validation saying that the Nationality- A,B,C already exists.

---

Expected Message:  Nationality- A,B,C already exists.

---

Actual Message I'am getting now is :  Nationality- A,B,C, already exists.
(Need to remove comma after C)

```
if(error.status === 409){
  this._commonSrvc.error('Nationality- '+this.getNationality(payLoad.custBkgGrpNationality) +' already exists +'.');
        return;
      }



private getNationality(Nationalities:any)
  { let Nationalitiesstr : String ="";
    for(let i=0; i<Nationalities.length; i++)
    {
      Nationalitiesstr = Nationalitiesstr + this.nationalityData.find(x => x.libraryID == Nationalities[i].nationalityXid).libraryName + ',';
    }
    return Nationalitiesstr; 
  }
```

Comment: Is this C# or javascript/Typescript? Please fix your tags

Comment: Instead of `+ ','` use this `+(i + 1 < Nationalities.length ? "," : "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the comma off the end of the string. Then add a check to see if `i` is less than the collection length - 1. Something like…

```
Nationalitiesstr = Nationalitiesstr + this.nationalityData.find(x => x.libraryID == Nationalities[i].nationalityXid).libraryName;

if (i < Nationalities.length -1)
  Nationalitiesstr += “, “;
```

The [String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) … may also work.